# Visitors to Data.gov by country of origin?

Tags: data-request, data.gov

Does anyone have summary data on visitors to data.gov by geography (country of origin)? I was able to find a summary last fall, but I can't seem to locate the data set or summary anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for filing the GitHub issue too Mitchell.

For background on this:

> Visitor stats by country and top states were retired with the new
>   data.gov theme launch about an year ago, earlier the process used to
>   be manual where we were taking the data from google analytics and
>   feeding the data to a visualization.
>
> Ideally we would need to integrate with google analytics api directly
>   and build on these visualization / metrics.

We're working on a sustainable way to display this information. For others on the Stack Exchange you can follow along here: https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/570